# jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection

Tags: jenkins, ssh, ansible

I am stuck to configure publish over ssh in jenkins.

Jenkins container to ansible container in CLI I am able to do SSH via private key, but the same private key when I am using on publish over ssh it does not work.

> jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect
> and initialize SSH connection. Message: [Failed to connect session for
> config [ansible]. Message [USERAUTH fail]]

Comment: Container Logs ..   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-07-02 19:28:33.607+0000 [id=18]    WARNING j.p.p.BapSshHostConfiguration#connect: Failed to connect session for config [ansible]. Message [Auth fail]
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem yesterday morning. In the ssh configuration file I added two lines, now working perfectly.

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa
```