# Deploy from GitHub (Use Jenkins and Nginx)

Tags: nginx, jenkins, deployment

I want ask the question.

I want to deploy from github to nginx server using jenkins. Maybe you can help me with this? When i try to add in Jenkins setting Publish over SSH i have error

```
jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to add SSH key. Message [invalid privatekey: [B@2a8ec46d]
```

I just started to study these technologies and most likely I am doing something wrong. Maybe i need configure my nginx files?

Also please tell me something links maybe with Guid how to deploy from GitHub using Jenkins and Nginx.

Comment: Ok problem with key was solved. But now i have next error
jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection. Message: [Failed to connect session for config [example].

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537762/jenkins-publish-over-ssh-shows-error-jenkins-plugins-publish-over-bappublishere) question from StackOverflow, someone faced the same problem and solution provided.

Answer (score 0):

Check first (in addition of [my old answer already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56538160/6309)) if you need to add [to your SSH daemon config file (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72865423/6309), as seen in [`jenkinsci/publish-over-ssh-plugin` issue 94](https://github.com/jenkinsci/publish-over-ssh-plugin/issues/94#issuecomment-1073190160):

```ini
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa
```